# agregar valores a una tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, estoy intentando ingresar valores a una tabla. De un formulario cualquiera. La idea es que sea el valor que se ingresado en los inputs, al momento de dar guardar, estos datos pasen a una pequeña tabla. Como podria hacerlo con javascript. Esto es lo que tengo:

```js
function guardar(){
   
    var _nom = document.getElementById("nomb").value;
    var _cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
    var _stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;
    // if(_nom.trim()==''){
    //     alert("Ingrese nombre del producto");
    // }
    // if(_cat.trim()==''){
    //     alert("Ingrese categoria del producto");

    // }
    // if(_precio.trim()==''){
    //     alert("Ingrese precio del producto");
        
    // }
    // if(_stock.trim()==''){
    //     alert("Ingrese stock del producto");
        
    // }

    var fila="<tr><td>"+_nom+"</td><td>"+_cat+"</td><td>"+_precio+"</td><td>"+_stock+"</td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("tablita").innerHTML = fila;
}
```

```css
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, td, th {
            border: 2px solid orange;
            padding:20px;
        }
        button{
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:orange;
            width:100px;
            height:25px;
            font-size:15px;
        }
```

```html
 Nombre: <input id="nomb" style="margin:10px" type="text"><br><br>
        Categoria:<input id="cat" style="margin:4px" type="text"><br><br>
        Precio: <input id="precio" style="margin:20px" type="text"><br><br>
        Stock: <input id="stock" style="margin:25px" type="text"><br><br>
        <button id="btn_guardar" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button><br><br>

        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolví mi duda.

```js
function guardar(){
   
    var _nom = document.getElementById("nomb").value;
    var _cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    var _precio = document.getElementById("precio").value;
    var _stock = document.getElementById("stock").value;

    var fila="<tr><td>"+_nom+"</td><td>"+_cat+"</td><td>"+_precio+"</td><td>"+_stock+"</td></tr>";

    var btn = document.createElement("TR");
    btn.innerHTML=fila;
    document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, td, th {
            border: 2px solid orange;
            padding:20px;
        }
        button{
            color:white;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:orange;
            width:100px;
            height:25px;
            font-size:15px;
        }
```

```html
 Nombre: <input id="nomb" style="margin:10px" type="text"><br><br>
        Categoria:<input id="cat" style="margin:4px" type="text"><br><br>
        Precio: <input id="precio" style="margin:20px" type="text"><br><br>
        Stock: <input id="stock" style="margin:25px" type="text"><br><br>
        <button id="btn_guardar" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button><br><br>

        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Solo tenia que trabajar con el método CreateElement();

Comment: También se puede hacer sin esa función, mediante un string. `document.innerHTML="<tr></tr>"`, pero la manera correcta es usando `createElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Colocale el id "tablita" en la etiqueta tbody

```
  <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tablita">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no quiere modificar tanto su código seguir el consejo de @Andres Castellanos , añadir la etiqueta `tbody` el ID que posee su tabla

```
<tbody id="tablita">
```

Si desea probar `JQuery` sería así , usando [After](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
  var fila='<tr><td> ' +_nom+'</td><td>'+_cat+'</td><td>'+_precio+
           '</td><td>'+_stock + '</td></tr>';
  $('#tablita tr:last').after(fila);
```

Comment: he considerado JQUERY, pero la idea es aprender mas sobre Javascript puro. Me dijeron que Jquery puede mal acostumbrarme. :/

Comment: Es verdad que se debe aprender primero Javascript y bien. pero JQuery sigue siendo una opción siempre :)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por el aporte. Yo hice mi propia versión y la comparto con vosotros. Saludos.

```js
var names=document.getElementsByName('name[]');

function InsertIntoTable()
{
  var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
 for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)
    TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + names[key].value + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);

  var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
 TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
 document.getElementById("TableBody").appendChild(TrElement);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="TextId">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="TextName">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="TextSurname">
  <input type="text" name="name[]" id="TextAge">
  <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="InsertIntoTable()">
  </br>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="TableBody">
     </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

```
    var names=document.getElementsByName('name[]');

    function InsertIntoTable()
    {
        var TableRow="<tr></tr>";

        for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)
            TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + names[key].value + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);

        var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
        TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
        document.getElementById("TableBody").appendChild(TrElement);
    }
```